# Daylight Saving Time issue

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, calendar, timezone, dst

I'm a noob working with someone else's old Google apps script that adds Event info collected from a Google form to an Event Calendar.
It all works great except the time is off by an hour. Example:

**User entered:**
Event start: 4/10/2023 7:30:00
Event end: 4/10/2023 9:15:00

**Calendar shows:**
Monday, April 10⋅8:30 – 10:15am

This is the script.
There is a DST offset at the very beginning.
There is a function to get a timezone offset at the bottom.(But it seems to be commented out.)

My users know what time their events will be held. We don't need any offset. What appears in the form responses should appear in the calendar.

Please tell me what I need to do to fix this.

```
const DST_HOURS = -0;

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const TARGET_CAL_ID = 'kinnschools.org_bunn4o6u6do0uvgmfiqo3ifp2o@group.calendar.google.com';
  // Fields: 0 = Timestamp, 1 = Email Address,  2 = Event Title:,   3 = Event Start:,   4 = Event End:, 
  // 5 = Building:, 6 = Room:,  7 = Presenter Contact Info :,   8 = Computer Services:, 
  // 9 = Custodial Services:,   10 = Food Services:,    11 = Additional Info:
  var title = e.values[5] + '-' + e.values[6] + ' ' + e.values[2] + ' (evnt1)';
  var description = '';
  var descObj = {
    'Event Submitted by': 1, 
    'Presenter Contact Info': 7, 
    'Computer Services': 8,
    'Custodial Services': 9, 
    'Food Services': 10,
    'Additional Info': 11
  };
  for (var f in descObj) {
    description += f + ':\n' + e.values[descObj[f]] + '\n\n';
  }
  var startTime = new Date(e.values[3]).addHours(),
      endTime = new Date(e.values[4]).addHours();
  var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(TARGET_CAL_ID).createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {
    description: description
  });
}


function testFormInput(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  var d = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 4).getValue();
  var values = ['_' + e.values[3], e.values[3], new Date(e.values[3]), d];
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1];
  sheet.appendRow(values);
}


Date.prototype.addHours = function() {
  this.setHours(this.getHours() + DST_HOURS);
  return this;
}


/*

function getTimeZoneOffsets() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1];
  //var s = '10/7/2019 12:50:00 -0500';
  var zones = sheet.getRange('B2:E2').getValues()[0].map(function(d) {
    return d.getTimezoneOffset();
  });
  Logger.log(zones);
}

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Four potentially different time zones are involved in the processing of events.

1. The user who enters a date string like `4/10/2023 7:30:00` lives in a time zone, but this is not mentioned anywhere, making the date string ambiguous.
2. Parsing an ambiguous date string like

   ```
   new Date("4/10/2023 7:30:00")
   ```

   creates a `Date` object in the time zone of the Google Apps *script* (see "Project Settings > General Settings > Time zone"). If this differs from the time zone of #1, the result can only be wrong. The following snippet shows how the date string can be made unambiguous by parsing the date *in the browser*, using the time zone of #1.

```html
Ambiguous date string:
<input name="datetime" type="datetime-local"
onchange="this.nextElementSibling.textContent=new Date(this.value).toISOString()"/>
Unambiguous date string:
<div></div>
```

3. The function `createEvent` takes `Date` objects for start and end, which have no ambiguity. When the Google calendar is exported, say, in the iCal format, the event is shown in the time zone of the Google *calendar* (see "Calendar settings > Time zone").
4. If a user views the calendar in their Google Calendar *app* (or web page), they see the event in the time zone specified in "Settings > General".

Check the three time zones from #2 through #4 in your case and whether they agree with the time zone you would assume in #1. If that does not explain what you observed, please edit your question and name these time zones.

(Adding `DST_HOURS` to a `Date` object is not a clean solution, especially given that a daylight saving time offset varies over the course of a year.)